# Flot canvas is not rendering in UI when using with knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js, flot

I have problem going on with flot grap and knockout js

**Flot Graph working when out side the knockout binding div**
In the fiddle the (div placeholder) for graph is nicely drawing if it is outside the knockout binding divs.
***Here is the jsfiddle*** - http://jsfiddle.net/keyur12/g9aLe/

**Flot Graph not working when inside the knocout binding div**
As soon as if we add the div placeholder inside the knockout binding div then the canvas for the flot grap is not working.
***Here is the jsfiddle*** - http://jsfiddle.net/keyur12/fGBBR/

```
<div style="float:left">
    Test 1
<h2>People</h2>
<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
    <!-- flot grap div inside knoutout binding -->
    <div id="placeholder" style="width:400px;height:300px;float:right"></div>

    <li> hi1 </li>
</ul>
<div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide any output in the javascript console?

Comment: Hi
thanks for your reply there is no console output. I have provide the two fiddles links above.

1) when placeholder div is outside knockout binding div -http://jsfiddle.net/keyur12/g9aLe/

2) when placeholder div is inside knockout biding - http://jsfiddle.net/keyur12/fGBBR/

I am looking for solution when placeholder div is inside knockout binding div why canvas for graphs are not rendering

Comment: Here is the console log if I put the placeholder div inside knockout binding div

Uncaught error invalid dimensions for plot, width = null, height = null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*All* markup within the foreach block is duplicated for *each* element within the array. So, in your markup above, you will have one

```
<div id="placeholder" style="width:400px;height:300px;float:right"></div>
```

for *each* person in the people array. So that will result in duplicate "placeholder" elements.

Also, you are trying to draw the graph in the document ready function with

```
 $.plot($("#placeholder"), data, options);
```

Which won't work because the element won't even exist yet. Can you explain what you are trying to do? Are you trying to draw a graph for each person? If so, you should create a custom binding (see: [custom binding doc](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found my own solution after some hard work and re-thinking.

Basically to make the flot graph work inside the knockout binding one has to identify how observables are assigned the values.

1. if **using getJSON call**
   if observables are assgined values inside the getJSON call then the `$.plot($("#placeholder0"), data, options);` should go inside getJSON call as well with unique index to placeholders. Not in `$(document).ready(function(){});`
   **example:**

   $.getJSON("someURL",function(data){
       self.someObservableArray(data.someArrayObjects);
       $.plot($("#placeholder0"), data, options);
     });
2. if **not using the getJSON call** then call to `$.plot($("#placeholder0"), data1, options);` should be in

   $(document).ready(function(){}); after ko.applybindings();

**example:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    ko.applybindings(new appModel());
    $.plot($("#placeholder0"), data, options);
    });
```

Here is the updated fiddle with working example - http://jsfiddle.net/keyur12/fGBBR/3/

Comment: While your fiddle works, you have hard-coded your initialization of the plots assuming you know the number of people in your array ahead of time. You really should use a custom binding instead. That way it will work regardless of the number of people you have.

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle with a very basic custom binding which you would want to expand upon: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fGBBR/4/)

Comment: Thanks Chuck your fiddle help me and gave much broader view. I appreciate your help :)